# Router.push reloads page with '?#' added to the URL

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When a user clicks sign-in button it fires this function to use AWS Cognito:

```
signIn() {
  let username = this.emailIn;
  let password = this.passwordIn;
  Auth.signIn(username, password)
    .then(user => {
      this.$router.push({ path: "dashboard" });
      this.$store.commit("SETUSER", user);
      this.$store.commit("CHANGESIGNEDIN", true);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

After the function fires the page reloads and adds a '?#' to the url. If I try to sign in again then it works properly...

I have a pretty straight forward setup in my index.js for Vue Router:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import Dashboard from "../views/Dashboard.vue";
import Leads from "../views/Leads.vue";
import SignUp from "../views/SignUp.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    component: Dashboard,
  },
  {
    path: "/leads",
    name: "Leads",
    component: Leads,
  },
  {
    path: "/signup",
    name: "SignUp",
    component: SignUp,
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a slash. Your line should be:

```
this.$router.push({ path: "/dashboard" });
```